# Setting the attribute on the creation date of multiple files

Tags: r, file, system

Could someone please help me with the following task. I have a lot of little text files that I "pulled" from a rather unusual control system. When I transfer files, I only receive the content of the files. Unfortunately, I lose all my attributes this way. And I care about the date of creation the most. I managed (using a camera and an OCR program) to bring about the fact that I already have a table with the names of the files and the correct creation dates. As below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = tibble(
  Name = c("name1.mpf", "name2.mpf", "name3.mpf", "name4.mpf", "name5.mpf"),
  Date = c("12/04/1997", "04/06/1998", "21/08/1998", "22/08/1998", "05/09/1999")
)

df = df %>% mutate(Date = dmy(Date))
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to go about setting the creation date of these files in R. I'm a beginner in R.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I have several hundred files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this. First create a project in RStudio (I assume you are using RStudio right now) and then create a new folder in the project directory, simply called Folder. Then put your files there with which you want to set the date.
Finally, make a `tibble` named `df` with the names and dates of your files.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(fs)

df = tibble(
  fileName = c("name1.mpf", "name2.mpf", "name3.mpf", "name4.mpf", "name5.mpf"),
  fileDate = c("12/04/1997", "04/06/1998", "21/08/1998", "22/08/1998", "05/09/1999")
)

df = df %>% mutate(fileDate = dmy(fileDate))
```

Now you need two additional functions. Don't worry if you don't understand everything. The functions are proven and tested so they work fine.

```
fGetInfo = function(file) file %>% file.info() %>% as_tibble()
fsetFileTime = function(data){ 
  data %>% mutate(
    result = case_when(
      is.na(fileDate) ~ "Missing date",
      !file_exists(file) ~ "File dont exist",
      TRUE ~ tryCatch(
        {
          res = "Error"
          if(Sys.setFileTime(file, fileDate)) res = "Date changed"
          res
        }, error = function(msg) res
      )
    )
  )
}
```

It's time to use the first one to read file attributes.

```
dffiles = tibble(
  file = dir_ls("Folder", regexp = "."),
  fileName = file %>% path_file(),
  id = 1:length(file)
) %>% 
  mutate(info = map(file, fGetInfo)) %>% 
  unnest(info)
dffiles
```

output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 10
  file             fileName     id  size isdir mode      mtime               ctime               atime               exe  
  <fs::path>       <chr>     <int> <dbl> <lgl> <octmode> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>
1 Folder/name1.mpf name1.mpf     1   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:19:55 2021-10-20 19:19:55 no   
2 Folder/name2.mpf name2.mpf     2   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:20:30 2021-10-20 19:20:30 no   
3 Folder/name3.mpf name3.mpf     3   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:20:29 2021-10-20 19:20:29 no   
4 Folder/name4.mpf name4.mpf     4   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:20:33 2021-10-20 19:20:33 no   
5 Folder/name5.mpf name5.mpf     5   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:20:32 2021-10-20 19:20:32 no   
6 Folder/name6.mpf name6.mpf     6   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:20:32 2021-10-20 19:20:32 no   
7 Folder/name7.mpf name7.mpf     7   452 FALSE 666       2021-08-03 02:00:00 2021-10-20 19:20:31 2021-10-20 19:20:31 no
```

As you can see there are 7 files in my folder (intentionally more than in df) and they all have today's date.
Now we need to join `tibble`s `dffiles` with `df`.

```
dffiles = dffiles %>% left_join(df, by="fileName") 
dffiles%>% 
  select(c(file, fileName, fileDate))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  file             fileName  fileDate  
  <fs::path>       <chr>     <date>    
1 Folder/name1.mpf name1.mpf 2021-08-03
2 Folder/name2.mpf name2.mpf 2021-08-03
3 Folder/name3.mpf name3.mpf 2021-08-03
4 Folder/name4.mpf name4.mpf 2021-08-03
5 Folder/name5.mpf name5.mpf 2021-08-03
6 Folder/name6.mpf name6.mpf NA        
7 Folder/name7.mpf name7.mpf NA
```

Finally, there is nothing else to do but set the dates for the appropriate files.

```
dffiles = dffiles %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  nest(data=c(file, fileDate)) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~fsetFileTime(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(result = result %>% factor()) 
dffiles %>% 
  select(c(file, fileName, fileDate, result))
```

output

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `id`
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   id [7]
     id file             fileName  fileDate   result      
  <int> <fs::path>       <chr>     <date>     <fct>       
1     1 Folder/name1.mpf name1.mpf 1997-04-12 Date changed
2     2 Folder/name2.mpf name2.mpf 1998-06-04 Date changed
3     3 Folder/name3.mpf name3.mpf 1998-08-21 Date changed
4     4 Folder/name4.mpf name4.mpf 1998-08-22 Date changed
5     5 Folder/name5.mpf name5.mpf 1999-09-05 Date changed
6     6 Folder/name6.mpf name6.mpf NA         Missing date
7     7 Folder/name7.mpf name7.mpf NA         Missing date
```

[image]

As you can see, everything worked out great!

Good luck with changing the date of all your files, no matter how many you have !!

Comment: Thank you! This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date))  %>% 
  mutate(Name = replace(Name, T, str_remove(Name,".mpf"))) %>% 
  unite("Filename",Name, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Filename=paste0(Filename,".mpf"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Check how it works and I will call you back soon.

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, but unfortunately your answer is **completely off topic**. I am looking for a way to change the **creation date** of the **physical files** on the disk, not the data mutation in the data frame!

Comment: That can be done if you are running Linux. Regarding MS Windows, I am not sure. So, if you are running Linux, I can help you.